# Outlook puts a link instead of a file to a message

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I tried to attach a file to a message in Outlook but instead the software put a link to the message. I can't figure out how to send a file with Outlook. How do I fix this? Was there some update which broke this or any idea why did it start doing this suddenly?

Comment: Can you add screenshots of what process you followed, and what you expect to happen please?

Comment: In Outlook, New Email, use the Attach File icon on the New Mail ribbon.

Comment: I just clicked New Email, put in recipient, subject, clicked in the body area, then the Attach file icon in the Message ribbon, selected the file from the list of recent files and was presented with a window showing box (box.com) storage. The only buttons available were Upload and Cancel. When I clicked cancel, nothing happened, file was not attached. When I repeated it, and clicked Upload, a link was added to the mail.

Comment: Try Repairing Office to see if that helps.

Comment: Is the file you're sharing saved in Box (the cloud storage client)?

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of your Outlook? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

And does this issue occur when adding a specific attachment or all the attachments?

According to your description, I notice that it starts doing this suddenly, have you done any specific operations before that?

Considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you try to start outlook in safe mode(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally.

If this is still the issue in safe mode, it is suggested that you could try to create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

In addition, if the above doesn't help, it's suggested that you could try to use the [Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-the-microsoft-support-and-recovery-assistant-e90bb691-c2a7-4697-a94f-88836856c72f) to check if there're any problems, which works by running tests to figure out what's wrong and offers the best solution for the identified problem.

Hope the above help!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Version is Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14326.20900) 64-bit
It's a business laptop so I'm not sure about any changes, updates are managed on corporate basis. Laptop asks for a reboot about once a week and I don't really know what exactly happens then. But now I tried again and outlook asked if I want to add a link or file. When I selected file it worked as usual. So maybe some temporary issue.

Comment: It's best that the problem disappears. If the problem occurs again, it's suggested that you could try the troubleshooting method I mentioned above.